# AVPlayer class & AVPlayerStatusFailed

Tags: ios, audio, streaming, avplayer

I'm using [AVPlayer class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for playing server mp3 URLs in our music streaming App. It works very well, however sometimes the AVPlayer status is set to "AVPlayerStatusFailed". And the documentation suggest that, when this happens we need to drop the current AVPlayer object and instantiate a new one.

This recovery approach fails sometimes, and when this recovery approach fails irrespective of how many times the AVPlayer object is reinitialised it is not playing any songs. Anybody faced simular issues? and have a solution ?

Comment: Do you release and nil the previous object ?

Comment: Also when you create the new object m do you check whether it is ready to play?